# Play Framework: Transform Result to Json

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, action

how can I transform a result to Json in an reusable action?

Example:

```
object JsonAction {

  def apply(block: Request[JsValue] => ???): Action[JsValue] = {
    Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
      val result = block(request)

      val finalResult = result.copy(body = Json.toJson(result.body))

      finalResult
    }
  }
}
```

in my controller:

```
def index = JsonAction { req =>
  Ok(new SomeModel(...))
}
```

The idea is to be able to seperate the result model and the representation as json (or xml for example).

I can not find a nice solution to this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc._


object JsonAction extends Results {
  def apply[A, B](block: A => B)(implicit reads: Reads[A], writes: Writes[B]): Action[JsValue] =
    Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
      val result = for {
        a <- Json.fromJson(request.body).asOpt
        b = block(a)
      } yield Ok(Json.toJson(b))
      result getOrElse InternalServerError(???)
    }
}
```

or you want to manually define resulting status in your block

```
object JsonAction extends Results {
  def apply[A, B](block: A => (Option[(Status, B)]), 
                  noneStatus: Result = BadRequest("could not parse json"))
                 (implicit reads: Reads[A], writes: Writes[B]): Action[JsValue] =
    Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
      val result = for {
        a <- Json.fromJson(request.body).asOpt
        (status, b) <- block(a)
      } yield status(Json.toJson(b))
      result getOrElse noneStatus
    }
}

object MathController {
  import JsonAction._
  def squareEquasion = JsonAction[Map[String, Double], Set[Double]] { map =>
    for {a <- map get "a"
         b <- map get "b"
         c <- map get "c"
         d = b * b - 4 * a * c} yield d match {
      case d if d < 0 => (InternalServerError, Set.empty[Double])
      case d if d == 0 => (Ok, Set(-b / 2 * a))
      case d if d > 0 => (Ok, Set(1, -1) map (q => (-b + q * math.sqrt(d)) / 2 * a))
    }
  }
}
```

and final attempt - here we are providing instance of `http.Writeable` implicitly using an `json.Writes` instance and converting value to JSON inside this instance, so we could use `Result` builders ad-hock. This actually could cause some ambiguity if type have it's own `Writeable` instance (e.g. `String`):

```
import play.api.http.Writeable
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.language.implicitConversions

object JsonAction {
  private object Res extends Results

  implicit def jsonWriteable[T](implicit writes: Writes[T]): Writeable[T] = {
    val jsonWriteable = implicitly[Writeable[JsValue]]
    def transform(obj: T) = jsonWriteable.transform(Json.toJson(obj))
    new Writeable[T](transform, jsonWriteable.contentType)
  }

  def apply[A, B](block: A => Option[Result],   noneStatus: Result = Res.BadRequest("could not parse json"))
                 (implicit reads: Reads[A], writes: Writes[B]): Action[JsValue] =
    Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
      val result = for {
        a <- Json.fromJson(request.body).asOpt
        result <- block(a)
      } yield result
      result getOrElse noneStatus
    }
}

object MathController extends Results{
  import JsonAction._
  def squareEquasion = JsonAction[Map[String, Double], Set[Double]] { map =>
    for {a <- map get "a"
         b <- map get "b"
         c <- map get "c"
         d = b * b - 4 * a * c} yield d match {
      case d if d < 0 => InternalServerError("No answer")
      case d if d == 0 => Ok(Set(-b / 2 * a))
      case d if d > 0 => Ok(Set(1, -1) map (q => (-b + q * math.sqrt(d)) / 2 * a))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately the important part to me was to be able to use Ok(new SomeModel(...)), so I can specify the status code very readable in my controller action.

Comment: Thanks again! Now this looks more like what I would like to achieve. There seems to be no way use "Ok(new SomeModel(...))" and then in JsonAction to call something like "val result = block(request); Json.toJson(result.getModel)" ?

Comment: I guess I could implement my own Results/Status components, but this would be a copy of https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2d1472370239b30a2f3a76c3372e8085ec3c61b1/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala with slight modifications... seems rather bad...